# I keep getting a NoSuchMethodError call in my Flutter application regarding Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck on this problem. I have been trying to render items from my Firestore collection. Everytime I try to retrieve it, I keep getting this error:

```
"Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: []("title")
Found: []() => Map<String, dynamic>"
```

I have tried to look online for solutions but I feel a bit stuck on what I am supposed to do. I have commented the part that is causing an error in the ListTile. This is something I have been stuck on in the past few days. I have all the dependencies installed such as the Firestore one so I don't think it is a dependency issue. Although I would greatly appreciate anyone who is able to help me by any chance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:tanbo_mobile/errorpage.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeTabState createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {
  

Future getPosts() async {

   var firestoreReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

   QuerySnapshot qn = await firestoreReference.collection('posts').get();

   return qn.docs;

}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child:
  FutureBuilder(
    future: getPosts(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {

        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );

      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

        return ListView.builder(
          // The length of our data we will return
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return ListTile(
                // This line is causing the errors!
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data['text']),
              );
            }
        );

      }

      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );

    },
  ),
 );
  

  }

}
```

[Image of error in application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjF3e.png)

[Firestore data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWBtt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DocumentSnapshot.data()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) is a method not a getter, therefore it's necessary to include the parentheses to actually call the method and obtain the returned `Map`. This is why dart is confused and throws an error as you're trying to use the `[]` operator on a function reference.

Replace the line that is giving you errors with the following:

```dart
title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data()['text']),
```